# Correctly handle utf8 string received from json.net

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, json.net

I'm using json.net to read data sent in json format from a server. The server encodes all string-type data it sends in json as utf-8.

Now to read the data in c# I do something like this: `string s = json.Value<string>("data");`

I assume the string `s` is now in utf-8 format, whereas the default encoding for strings in c# is utf-16 (unicode).

To convert the string to unicode, would this be correct?

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
string unicode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

What I want (I think) is the raw bytes from `s` and then pass that to the utf-8 decoder to get unicode, but I'm not sure what exactly `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` gives me, or what I should use instead.

Comment: You can't double parse it. But what is wrong with your string in the first place, since all strings in .NET are UTF16?

Comment: Well the string is received as utf-8, I assumed I had to do something, but if json.net automatically handles this then it's ok as you say, but I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: I think you need to swap it. `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)` and then `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)`. This way you will convert the UTF8 to Unicode.

Comment: In your question you have a variable called `json` -- how does that get populated?   Is there some kind of stream being read from a web response?  If so, you want to pass `Encoding.UTF8` to the stream reader.

Comment: You are right, I just discovered the data is read from the socket using `Encoding.Default.GetString` which isn't exactly optimal. Using `Encoding.UTF8`there directly should fix all problems with utf-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert anything, since `string` objects in .NET [are encoded in UTF-16](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/04/09/why-utf-16/).

If there is anything to change, you should change something where JSON.NET deserializes the string: you can't double parse it. The incoming JSON string is already interpreted for a specific encoding. You can't go back from there without the original bytes.

Comment: If the json data that is received looks like this: `{ "data" : "strÃ¶" }` it definitely needs to be converted becase it will look exactly like that in the c# string as well.

Comment: Are you sure all goes well on the other end?

Comment: You were correct; the string that was parsed by json was created from the raw data from the socket using `Encoding.Default` instead of `Encoding.UTF8`.